# exclude nestedfields in mongoDB not working

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin

How can you exclude nested fields? E.g.

```
{
     "user": {
                "_id": "65d0fd1aa10f95578e5c3c94",
                "person_id": "65d0fd1aa10f95578e5c3c93",
                "usesAgent": "false"
      }
}
```

Doing this doesn't work? I can only get it working on top level fields

```
Aggregation.project().andExclude("user.person_id")
```

***UPDATE***

```
 AggregationOperation {
                Document("\$project", Document("user", Document("person_id", 0)))
            }
```

Comment: Not sure, but since you do not show your Kotlin data model I wonder if this is a term naming issue - maybe the terms used here need to be the Kotlin field names not the Mongo field names.  Assuming the standard Kotlin conventions are set to be converted to snake naming in Mongdo, then perhaps you should try `Aggregation.project().andExclude("user.personId")`

Comment: my data class is the same in Kotlin, for id fields I use person_id, others, I use standard convention. I don't think Mongo db supports this. It can only exclude non-nested fields

Answer (score 0):

In pure mongoDB you can use the projection:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {"user.person_id": 0}}
])
```

Or even in a simple query:

```
db.collection.find({},{"user.person_id": 0})
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/b11ePd5WnH9)

Comment: This works in the playground but I'm trying to find the kotlin equivalent